# Converting text from unsupported encodings like 866 into known by Mathematica?

Tags: import, java, character-encoding

The list of character encodings currently supported by *Mathematica* is still extremely limited. For example, it supports only three standard [IBM PC (OEM) code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#IBM_PC_.28OEM.29_code_pages):

```
Select[$CharacterEncodings, StringMatchQ[#, "CP" ~~ __] &]
```

> ```
> {"CP936", "CP949", "CP950"}
> ```

Java already [has built-in support for many standard code pages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) including [code page 866](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_866) which I'm currently interested in.

[Here is an example text](http://pastebin.com/raw/BtTxh0U6) as a `"Byte"` sequence originally encoded using code page 866 which can easily be obtained on Russian-localized Windows with the following command:

```
i = Import["!help", "Byte"]
Export["i.txt", i]
```

From the above link the `"Byte"` sequence can be restored using the command:

```
Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/BtTxh0U6", "List"] == i
```

> ```
> True
> ```

How to decode in *Mathematica* a `String` (or a `"Byte"` sequence) encoded using [code page 866](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_866)?

---

P.S. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4850645/590388) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/229015/590388) contain potentially useful pieces of code in Java. From the second link it seems that I should use either [`Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) or [`CharsetDecoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html)  class but I can't figure out how to continue from the following:

```
Needs["JLink`"];
InstallJava[];

charsetDecoderClass = LoadJavaClass["java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder"];

charsetClass = LoadJavaClass["java.nio.charset.Charset"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATE 3

Probably the most elegant complete solution (output is truncated):

```
Needs["JLink`"];
InstallJava[];

ImportString[
 JavaBlock[JavaObjectToExpression[JavaNew["java.lang.String", i, "CP866"]]], "Text"]
```

> ```
> "Для получения сведений об определенной команде наберите HELP <имя команды>
> ASSOC          Вывод либо изменение сопоставлений по расширениям имен файлов.
> ATTRIB         Отображение и изменение атрибутов файлов.
> BREAK        Включение и выключение режима обработки комбинации клавиш CTRL+C.
> BCDEDIT        Задает свойства в базе данных загрузки для управления начальной
>                загрузкой.
> CACLS          Отображение и редактирование списков управления доступом (ACL)
>                к файлам.
> ```

Packaged as a function:

```
Needs["JLink`"];
InstallJava[];

decodeCP866[b : {__Integer}] := 
  ImportString[JavaBlock[JavaObjectToExpression[JavaNew["java.lang.String", b, "CP866"]]],
    "Text"];
decodeCP866[s_String] := decodeCP866[ImportString[s, "Byte"]]
```

---

### UPDATE 2

A bit ugly method to get rid of unwanted `"\r"` in the output using Java only (output is truncated):

```
Needs["JLink`"];
InstallJava[];

JavaBlock[JavaNew["java.lang.String", i, "CP866"]@
  replace[MakeJavaObject@"\r\n", MakeJavaObject@"\n"]]
```

> ```
> "Для получения сведений об определенной команде наберите HELP <имя команды>
> ASSOC          Вывод либо изменение сопоставлений по расширениям имен файлов.
> ATTRIB         Отображение и изменение атрибутов файлов.
> BREAK        Включение и выключение режима обработки комбинации клавиш CTRL+C.
> BCDEDIT        Задает свойства в базе данных загрузки для управления начальной
>                загрузкой.
> ```

Two alternatives using `StringReplace`:

```
StringReplace[JavaBlock[JavaObjectToExpression[JavaNew["java.lang.String", i, "CP866"]]], 
 "\r\n" -> "\n"]
```

or

```
StringReplace[JavaBlock[JavaNew["java.lang.String", i, "CP866"]@toString[]], 
 "\r\n" -> "\n"]
```

However it would be much nicer to be able to switch off the addition of `"\r"` by Java.

---

### UPDATE 1

Actually the problem can be solved as simple as

```
Needs["JLink`"];
InstallJava[];

JavaBlock[JavaObjectToExpression[JavaNew["java.lang.String", i, "CP866"]]]
```

No need to load any classes explicitly and it is sufficient to pass the name of charset as `String`!

But I still haven't found a way to avoid conversion of `"\n"` into `"\r\n\"`. The following piece of code has no effect:

```
sys = LoadJavaClass@"java.lang.System";
sys@setProperty["line.separator", "\n"]
```

---

### Original answer

Loading the [`Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) `JavaClass`:

```
Needs["JLink`"];
InstallJava[];

LoadJavaClass["java.nio.charset.Charset"]
```

> ```
> JavaClass[java.nio.charset.Charset,<>]
> ```

Creating `JavaObject` corresponding to the CP866 charset:

```
cp866CharsetObject = Charset`forName["CP866"]
```

> ```
> «JavaObject[sun.nio.cs.IBM866]»
> ```

Converting a `"Byte"` sequence into a [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) `JavaObject`, then converting this object into *Mathematica* expression and releasing this `JavaObject` (output is truncated):

```
JavaBlock[JavaObjectToExpression[JavaNew["java.lang.String", i, cp866CharsetObject]]]
```

> ```
> "Для получения сведений об определенной команде наберите HELP <имя команды>
>
> ASSOC          Вывод либо изменение сопоставлений по расширениям имен файлов.
>
> ATTRIB         Отображение и изменение атрибутов файлов.
>
> BREAK        Включение и выключение режима обработки комбинации клавиш CTRL+C.
>
> BCDEDIT        Задает свойства в базе данных загрузки для управления начальной
>
>                загрузкой.
> ```

The only problem with this solution is that it decodes the newline characters as `"\r\n\"` what *Mathematica* interprets as two newline characters instead of one.

Comment: [Here](http://superuser.com/a/1045485/71768) is an alternative solution by modifying the registry default settings for CMD. With this one can simply use `Import["!help", "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "WindowsCyrillic"]` on Russian-localized Windows.