# Importing and dealing with foreign languages

Tags: character-encoding

I am importing a text file with Swedish letters (å, ä, ö).

A. If I use `ReadList["sv_JSPFirefox.txt"]`, it imports the file nicely but then I cannot use a command line like:

```
dict2 = Select[dict1, Not@StringContainsQ[#, Alternatives @@ rejectlist] &]
```

The error code is:

```
StringContainsQ::strse: String or list of strings expected at position 1 
in StringContainsQ[Aapua,.|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,
I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z}|Å|Ä|Ö]. >>
```

Two screen dumps show the problem better:
[image: Importing Swedish characters OK]
[image: Importing Swedish characters error]

B. If I use: `ReadList["sv_JSPFirefox.txt, Word]` it imports the file but those characters are a mess; but at least I can use the command above and proceed; but commands (search, etc) including these characters do work properly.

I have tried to add "UTF8", "UTF-8","Unicode", "Lines" and other options but nothing seems to help. Any pointer in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

20160306 Edit.
@C.E. I made a sample file and a very small file called "shrimpsandwich.txt". This is enough because this is a word in Swedish that contains all three letters, "räksmörgås". You might have heard of smörgåsbord.

[image: Trials and errors]

Sample files:
A small sample file is displayed in the screen dump above.

Comment: I can generate several error messages when I try to import a file with åäö in it using `ReadList`, but I can't reproduce your problem. Can you provide a file - does not have to be your entire file, it can be a smaller one - as well as a definition for `rejectlist` so that we can reproduce the problem? Also have you tried using `Import`? (e.g. `StringSplit@Import[file]`)

Comment: @Xavier, yes it is True. Thanks.

Comment: I tried two different character encodings yesterday but I [could not reproduce your error message](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LvMxz.png). Please post all of your code as copyable text and I will try using that. btw `DictionaryLookup[{"Swedish", Repeated[___ ~~ "å" | "ä" | "ö" ~~ ___, {3, Infinity}]}]` clearly shows that räksmörgås is not the only word in Swedish with å, ä and ö in it.

Comment: Thanks, @Xavier. dict2 becomes all OK but then again when I try to remove words containing characters in the "rejectlist" (capital letters, numbers etc.) it all reverses to gibberish for those letters. I do not understand why it is so, though. Is there another way? I suppose so, but I would like to understand why (but we can come back to that later). `dict3 = Select[dict2, 
  Not@StringContainsQ[#, Alternatives @@ idagThrowAway] &]`

Comment: @C.E and @Xavier using the suggestion `dict1 = ToString /@ ReadList["sv_JSPFirefox.txt"]` it all works! Awesome! Now, the question arises in my mind: What was the problem, and what is different in this solution? If you have some time, please do explain.

Comment: What is th procedure here? Should I edit the whole page and remove unnecessary comments of mine, screen dumps etc? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that would be alright. You are writing for two audiences: answerers and readers. Neither wants the question to be bloated, and answerers want easy access to whatever work has already been done (code, insights). As you try to improve the question it is normal to remove some old parts that no longer have any purpose.

Comment: Potentially related: "[Converting text from unsupported encodings like 866 into known by Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99458/280)"

Comment: @Xavier, I know that the procedure here recommends that I should upvote your answer but I cannot see where to do it!?

Comment: @C.E. Thank you. At the bottom, there is a button marked "Answer your question". Should I write in there the solution given above by @Xavier? Just to make it easier for people to find the answer? Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: @JSP Well, you can wait for Xavier to see your previous comment to him; once he sees that you want to upvote his suggestion then he might post it as an answer to allow you to do that. If it solves your problem and he posts it as an answer you can also "accept it", there will be a checkmark button next to the answer for that. If he doesn't post it as an answer then you are free to post it as an answer yourself, giving proper credit to Xavier of course. You can even accept answers that you've posted yourself, and it is recommended in cases where the question would otherwise go unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the discussion above which might give some other insights, the answer by @Xavier solves the problem. Thank you all, for taking the time to test and answer.

Solution:

```
dict1 = ToString /@ ReadList["sv_JSPFirefox.txt"]
```